# How do I plot a convenient lognormal pdf with my data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, probability-density, probability-distribution

I have a random variable *Words per sentence* which contains those values:

```
words_per_sentence = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 58, 62, 67, 67, 73, 80]
```

The observation space contains 500 values (*N=500*), and the mean and standard deviation are:

- *mu = 15.088*
- *sigma = 12.445*

I want to calculate a **three-parameters-lognormal PDF** for my variable and **plot it in a graph** but I do not get the result I want. This is my failing code up to now:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 54, 54, 55, 58, 62, 67, 67, 73, 80]
plt.hist(data, bins=50, color='c', alpha=0.75)
xmin = min(data)
xmax = max(data)
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200)
pdf = stats.lognorm.pdf(x, s=12.445, loc=1, scale=math.exp(15.088))
plt.plot(pdf, 'y')
```

The problem is that I do not get the PDF printed but a straight horizontal line in at the bottom of the graph. I cannot post any picture as I have not yet enough punctuation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The character class you have there does not allow spaces. Add a space to it:

```
^[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚÜ ]+:
```

(Edited to add the `Ñ` that it needs)

Comment: Yeah, I have tried but id does not work

Comment: I think it doesn't work because you don't have `Ñ` in the character class, either.  Try other examples with other multiple names, but no diacritics.

Comment: No, it is not the problem :(

Comment: Given the code and sample data you've shown us, it sure looks like it's the problem. But we can't really tell because you're not showing us any code or telling us how you're testing things. In fact, we don't even know what language or tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^[\p{Lu}\s]+:
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/iQU4sH/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\p{Lu}\s]+              any character of: Unicode uppercase letter (\p{Lu}),
                           whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and &quot; &quot;) 
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'</pre>
```

If it does not work use

```
^[^:\r\n]+:
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^:\r\n]+                any character except: ':', '\r' (carriage
                           return), '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
```